# How does the change in horizontal shift of the top edge of the cube equal to square root of 2 times the change in diagonal?

Tags: geometry

I was reading about [*shear stress*](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_38.html#Ch38-S2) from *Feynman's Lectures on Physics Vol 2* . There he then expressed the shear stress "in terms of the angle $\theta$ by which the cube is twisted" i.e.,

$$\theta = \frac{\delta}{l}$$ where $\delta$ is the "horizontal shift of the top edge" of the cube.

[image]

But then he wrote

$$\delta = \sqrt 2\Delta D$$

> **From the geometry of the figure** you can see that the horizontal shift $\delta$ of the top edge is equal to $\sqrt 2\Delta D.$ So
>
> $$\theta =\frac{\delta} l=\frac{\sqrt 2\Delta D}l=2\frac{\Delta D}D.$$

But I didn't get how he deduced that. Could anyone please shed some light on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remind yourself that the picture is very large expansion of what is going on. The deformation of the box is minimum.

That is why you have in the first place $\theta=\dfrac{\delta}{l}$ and not $\tan\theta=\dfrac{\delta}{l}$...

You have then $\Delta D$ parallel (EDIT: I wrote initially perpendicular instead of parallel) to $D$, and at a $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ angle from $\delta$, hence the $\delta=\sqrt 2 \Delta D$

Comment: `ΔD perpendicular to D` - I couldn't get the visualisation. Could you break this to me?

Comment: $\Delta D$ is in fact parallel to $D$. Most of the difference, if we are close to the initial square configuration, if along the length of $D$.

Comment: Because $D$ is the diagonal of the square (planar section of the cube), and $\delta$ is parallel to the side of the said square.